# Why Microsoft Word disregards page break

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I'm using Word all the time and I've been using/adding Page Breaks since 90's, but this particular document which was not created by me has page break which is ignored by Word. Naturally I tried to delete it and just add another one, but the new break on the same spot is being ignored as well.

When I say "ignore" I meant the Word actually sees and displays properly the page break during the editing, but when you print the document or at least do Print Preview, then it's just disregards the break like it's not there.

I am able to add a break at the end of the document and it works, but not at that particular spot. The document is very complex (it's a court document) with heavy formatting and lots of tables, so I'm trying to avoid copy-n-pasting or recreating the new document from scratch.

Any ideas why?

Here's a clue (although it maybe nothing): Under this faulty Page Break, Word displays the dotted line. I don't see that line under other page breaks, so it must mean something, unfortunately I can't find the definition, because Google search wrong topics related to dotted lines. Please advice.

- Picture of the Page Break symbol, that doesn't work

  [image: Picture of the Page Break symbol, that doesn't work]
- Picture of the same document in Print Preview mode, with completely ignored page break symbol

  [image: Picture of the same document in Print Preview mode, with completely ignored page break symbol]

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that page break and its paragraph mark haven't accidentally been formatted as "hidden text" (select them, press CTRL d to bring up dialog box and make sure that the box Hidden Text isn't ticked).

Comment: Thank you Tanya - that's exactly what it was. Even when I was deleting the line break, the attribute information (as typically in Word) resides after each character, so when I deleted the line break and then added again, the hidden attribute remained there, so the new break was hidden as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered by Tanya in the comment section. The line break character had hidden attribute. I simply didn't that the dotted underline means the content is hidden.